# How to add a ui component (materialize stepper) into a vue project?

Tags: vue.js

I'm looking for a material design stepper ui component for a vue project. I have a project built using Vue Cli. Vuetify has a stepper component, but it has some builtin styles like textarea that replaced original style, so I don't want to use. So I found this Materialize-stepper.

https://kinark.github.io/Materialize-stepper/

This usage does not say how to use it in vue project. So how to add this component (or any components like this) into vue?

I added these two lines in index.html

Then I make a new text.vue file like this, but it's not working. What to do?

```
<template>
  <div class="test">
      <ul class="stepper linear">
        <li class="step active">
          <div class="step-title waves-effect">E-mail</div>
          <div class="step-content">
            <!-- Your step content goes here (like inputs or so) -->
            <div class="step-actions">
              <!-- Here goes your actions buttons -->
              <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn next-step">CONTINUE</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
var stepper = document.querySelector(".stepper");
var stepperInstace = new MStepper(stepper, {
  // options
  firstActive: 0 // this is the default
});
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Then it shows this error, what to do?

```
mstepper.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null
    at mstepper.min.js:10
    at E._init (mstepper.min.js:10)
    at new E (mstepper.min.js:10)
    at eval (test.vue?1174:178)
    at Object../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/test.vue (app.js:774)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at eval (test.vue?edbc:1)
    at Object../src/components/test.vue (app.js:2019)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
```